# How to read user input of various types in C?

Tags: c

This might be a dumb question, but I'm new to C and I realized that if you want to use `scanf`, you have to give it a type you're scanning. But what if you don't know what the user will type, how can you give it a definite type?

For example, I want the user to able to give various commands such as

```
read file.txt
write file2.txt
delete 2 
delete 4
quit
```

I started off by doing

```
printf("\nPlease enter a command (print, delete, write, quit): ");
scanf("%s", &str); //but I realized here how can I differentiate it? 
//i won't know what the user will type beforehand so I can't give a definite type.
```

Comment: this `scanf("%s", &str);` is almost surely wrong.

Comment: regarding scanf() and family of functions:  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the function was successful.  2) %s will stop when it sees any white space (space, tab, newline)  3) an array name devolves to a pointer to the first byte of the array (and scanf() parameters must be pointers) so use 'str', not '&str'  4) when using certain of the format conversion specifiers, I.E. %s, there is no limit on how many characters can be input.  suggest using a length modifier on the %s to force scanf to stop before overflowing the input 'str' buffer.

Comment: Such as `char str[100]; ret=scanf("%99s", str);`

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks, I forgot to include an example

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `scanf()` for each of the listed inputs will be ONLY the first word (up to but not including the space). Suggest using `fgets()` to get the whole command line input into a local buffer, then parsing the data fields from the local buffer, perhaps using `strtok()` or `strchr()` or ...

Comment: It's a good answer, since OP's spec has input which includes spaces. It will be far easier to parse a string than deal with the vagaries of the horrible `scanf()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane true, I didn't notice that so my answer is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead try something like this?

```
int option;
printf("\nPlease enter a command (1 for print, 2 for delete, 3 for write, 4 for quit): ");
```

And then read the user input number

```
scanf("%d", &option);
```

You can later use a switch statement on 'option' to process differently

Comment: A good answer since OP says "if you don't know what the user will type, how can you give it a definite type?" and indeed how can you meaningfully process any responses without OP defining his language, and its syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a switch-like solution. `switch` doesn't support `char *`, so else-if is needed.

```
int x;
char buff[MAX_LEN], buff1[MAX_LEN];

scanf("%s", buff);
if (!strcmp(buff, "read")) {
    scanf("%s", buff1);
    //...
} else if (!strcmp(buff, "delete")) {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //...
} else if (!strcmp(buff, "quit")) {
    //...
    exit(0);
} else {
    //Error handle
}
```